# How I can access data in a bidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need help to access data in all field, the original data provide from json object and already decode in array $from

this is a print_r($from) result :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ([numberOfResult] => 1 [idUsager] => 1 [idUnique] => 1880e784 [codeLanguage] => fr [language] => Français [idCountry] => 66 [country] => Québec - Montréal [photo] => /usagers/1/1880e784/1880e784.png [pseudo] => PLATiNUM2727 [firstName] => Bedard [lastName] => Gabriel [ddn] => 1994-08-19 [mindText] => new status [compteVerifie] => 2012-01-03 [online] => 10 [onlineDescription] => En ligne [iSearch] => 3 [iSearchDescription] => Amis [level] => 5000 [levelDescription] => Administrateur [lookingFor] => partys & événements, Sexe, Autre..., [myInterest] => nature [myFavoriteBooks] => Dan Brown [myFavoriteMovies] => action [myFavoriteMusic] => Trance4Ever [myFavoriteTvShows] => CSI Miami [description] => description [dateDescrWaitingApproval] => 2012-07-17 17:38:23 [dateDescrApprouved] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [descriptionWaiting] => test [lastModification] => 2012-10-06 20:51:59 [bodyType] => Costaud [carOwner] => Non [homeOwner] => Non [smoking] => Non [drinking] => Socialement [drug] => Rarement [eyeColor] => Brun pâle [hairColor] => Bruns pâles [education] => BACC Universitaire gradué [height] => 5'7" (170 cm) [weight] => 196 lbs (89 kg) [relationshipStatus] => Célibataire [sexualOrientation] => Préfère ne pas dire [zodiac] => Capricorne [job] => Informatique ) )`
```

How can i access to [numberOfResult] or [firstName] for example ?

Comment: Also, "multidimensional", not "double".

Comment: @AlexLunix: "Bidimensional" to be precise. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$from[0]['numberOfResult']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is example table of 2D array,

[image]

Code to access and display above table in PHP to HTML.

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Manual access to each element</h1>";

echo $shop[0][0]." costs ".$shop[0][2]." and you get ".$shop[0][2]."<br />";
echo $shop[1][0]." costs ".$shop[1][3]." and you get ".$shop[1][2]."<br />";
echo $shop[2][0]." costs ".$shop[2][4]." and you get ".$shop[2][2]."<br />";

echo "<h1>Using loops to display array elements</h1>";

echo "<ol>";
for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++)
{
    echo "<li><b>The row number $row</b>";
    echo "<ul>";

    for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++)
    {
        echo "<li>".$shop[$row][$col]."</li>";
    }

    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ol>";
?>
```

Reference [Link](http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/multidimensional_arrays.php#twodim)

i hope this will help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for `[numberOfResult]` use this

```
echo $from[0]['numberOfResult'];
```

and for `[firstName]` use this

```
echo $from[0]['firstName'];
```